# Использовать material Chip components с не material темой

Tags: android

Возможно ли использовать

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11111"/>
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

при использовании `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Сейчас фатальная ошибка из-за тему приложения

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
```

p.s. Добавить сторонние библиотеки или поменять тему пока не могу..
Или может есть возможность реализовать такое же с помощью recyclerView (без подключения библиотек)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте к вашей `ChipGroup` добавить `theme`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
```

т.е. должно получиться как то так:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11111"/>
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Comment: Да, это работает! Что я только не пробовал с style, а нужно было theme :) Спасибо!!